# IPC System V - Message Queue creation

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc, message

I have miss understood problem about multiple message queue creation in IPC System V.

My problem is: A main process creates NB_fils child process. Each process (include the main process) possesses a message queue. The child process i (0 <= i < NB_fils) possesses the message queue mq[i]. The main process possesses the message queue mq[NB_Fils]. The children generate a message and send to the message queue of the main process. The main process back to the child process exactly max_msg_i value.

Here is my work:

```
#define SVID_SOURCE 1
#define NB_FILS 4
#define MSG_SIZE 128 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

/* Message structure */
typedef struct msgbuf{
    long mtype; 
    int msg_val; 
    int mq_index; 
    } message_buf; 

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int mq[NB_FILS + 1]; /* There are totally NB_FILS + 1 message queues */
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0; 
    int proc_index = -1; 
    char path[14] = "File_msg";
    key_t cle; 
    int max_msg_i = 0; 
    message_buf msg_send; 
    message_buf msg_rcv; 

    /* Creation of NB_FILS + 1 message queues */
    for(i = 0; i < NB_FILS + 1; i++){
        /* cle = ftok(".", i); */ <=======================================
         cle = ftok(path, i);     <=======================================
        mq[i] = msgget(cle, 0666|IPC_CREAT);
        }

    /* Creation of NB_FILS child process */
    for(i = 0; i < NB_FILS; i++){
        if(fork() > 0)
            break; 
        } 

    /* The child process */
    if(i != NB_FILS){
        int somme = 0; 
        proc_index = i; 
        printf("(Pid=%d) My index is %d\n", getpid(), proc_index);

        /* Message creation */      
        srand(getpid()); 
        max_msg_i =  (int) (NB_FILS*(float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
        msg_send.msg_val = max_msg_i; 
        msg_send.mtype = 1L; 
        msg_send.mq_index = proc_index; 
        printf("(Pid=%d) I'm waiting for %d messages from the main process\n", getpid(), msg_send.msg_val);

        /* Send message to message queue associated with the main process */
        msgsnd(mq[NB_FILS], &msg_send, 2*sizeof(int) + sizeof(long), 1L); 

        /* At the owned message queue, child process waits for max_msg_i message sent from the main process */
        for(j = 0; j < max_msg_i; j++){
            msgrcv(mq[proc_index], &msg_rcv, 2*sizeof(int) + sizeof(long), 1L, 0);
            printf("(Pid=%d) I have received the message containing value %d of from the main process \n", getpid(), msg_rcv.msg_val); 
            somme += msg_rcv.msg_val; 
            }

        printf("(Pid=%d) Sum of %d values received: %d\n", getpid(), max_msg_i, somme);

        /* Drop the queue message */ 
        msgctl(mq[proc_index], IPC_RMID, 0);
        }

    /* The main process */
    else{
        srand(time(NULL)); 
        /* At the owned message queue, the main process wait for values max_msg_i (1 <= max_msg_i <= NB_FILS) sent by 
         * the child process and send back to them max_msg_i messages. */
        for(i = 0; i < NB_FILS; i++){
            msgrcv(mq[NB_FILS], &msg_rcv,2*sizeof(int) + sizeof(long), 1L, 0); 
            printf("(P)J'ai reçu le message: msg_val = %d, mq_index = %d\n", msg_rcv.msg_val, msg_rcv.mq_index); 

            /* Creat max_msg_i messages and send to process i */    
            for(j = 0; j < msg_rcv.msg_val; j++){
                msg_send.msg_val =  (int) (100*(float)rand()/RAND_MAX);
                msg_send.mtype = 1L; 
                msg_send.mq_index = msg_rcv.mq_index; 
                msgsnd(mq[msg_rcv.mq_index], &msg_send, 2*sizeof(int) + sizeof(long), 1L); 
                }
            }

        /* Drop the queue message */
        msgctl(mq[NB_FILS], IPC_RMID, 0);  
        }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
    }
```

My problem is focus in 2 lines:

```
 cle = ftok(".", i);  <=======================================
  /* cle = ftok(path, i); */     <=======================================
```

When I tried to use cle = ftok(".", i), it's worked fine. But for the other, it's always show
like:

```
(Pid=3813) My index is 0
(Pid=3813) I'm waiting for 1 messages from the main process
(Pid=3813) I have received the message containing value 1 of from the main process 
(Pid=3813) Sum of 1 values received: 1
(Pid=3814) My index is 1
(Pid=3814) I'm waiting for 3 messages from the main process
(Pid=3814) I have received the message containing value 3 of from the main process 
(Pid=3815) My index is 2
(Pid=3815) I'm waiting for 2 messages from the main process
(Pid=3814) I have received the message containing value 2 of from the main process 
(Pid=3816) My index is 3
(Pid=3816) I'm waiting for 0 messages from the main process
(Pid=3814) I have received the message containing value 0 of from the main process 
(Pid=3814) Sum of 3 values received: 5
(Pid=3815) I have received the message containing value -1080789062 of from the main process 
(Pid=3815) I have received the message containing value -1080789062 of from the main process 
(Pid=3815) Sum of 2 values received: 2133389172
(P)I have received: msg_val = -1080789062, mq_index = 47
(P)I have received: msg_val = -1080789062, mq_index = 47
(P)I have received: msg_val = -1080789062, mq_index = 47
(P)I have received: msg_val = -1080789062, mq_index = 47
(Pid=3816) Sum of 0 values received: 0
```

It like the message is not sent exactly.

Could any one can tell me what is the problem.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You may start checking the return value of `ftok` to see whether has failed. Try giving the full path of `File_msg` too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify an **existing file** for the first parameter when calling ftok().
As "." points to the local directly (which exists), this is valid in your example.
But I doubt that a file named "File_msg" exists in the current directory, therefore you get an error.
Use a relative or absolute path to an existing file instead.